# Is there a notion of a complex derivative or complex integral?

Tags: calculus, analysis, complex-numbers, fractional-calculus

While reading about fractional calculus in http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110241.pdf , I came across the following quote:

> Fractional integration and fractional differentiation are generalisations of notions of integer-order integration and differentiation, and include n-th derivatives and n-folded integrals (n denotes an integer number) as particular cases.

Let $D = \frac{d}{dx}$ .

We have found meaningful notions of $D^2$ and $D^{-1}$ (derivative and antiderivative, respectively, of integer-order) and $D^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (derivative of fractional-order) , and we can say that integer differentiation (where given $D^n , n \in \mathbb{Z}$) is a special case of more general fractional differentiation (where given $D^n , n \in \mathbb{R}$).

I'm wondering if there's some meaningful notion of "complex differentiation", say something like $D^i$, where fractional differentiation is a special case (note that anti differentiation is a special case of differentiation; namely, given $D^n$, anti differentiation occurs when $n$ is real and negative). Is this conceivable? If so, are there any apparent applications of this?

Sorry if this is a dumb question (by dumb, I mean something that I could've found elsewhere online). I've searched around and haven't found anything on this yet.

Comment: The tag "fractional-calculus" answers half of your question.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I didn't know about fractional calculus before and just reading the wikipedia article was fascinating.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  One could perhaps start with [Fractional derivatives of imaginary order](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-3/2/241.extract) by E.R. Love (from 1971).  This is still an active area of research.  (Contrast "fractional calculus", which frequently starts with the Riemann-Liouville differintegral, neither of whom are particularly recent publishers.)  See, for instance, [Fractional Integrals of Imaginary Order in the Space of Hölder Functions with Polynomial Weight on an Interval](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1025063031729) or [Definitions of Complex Order Integrals and Complex Order Derivatives Using Operator Approach](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0400.pdf).  (The latter essentially extends the R-L differintegral slightly.)

Part of the difficulty is identifying functions that can be differentiated imaginarily- (or complexly-) many times.  It would be nice to just have a supply of spaces of functions that can be differintegrated in such a way, and whose set relationships with each other and other well studied spaces of functions were known, but we're not quite there yet.

Comment: ah great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can present an example problem with a complex fractional derivative. Consider the Cauchy pulse (Ref: S.L. Hahn, *Hilbert Transforms in Signal Processing*, Artech House, 1996)

$$\psi=\frac{1}{1-i\tau}$$

Differentiating $n$ times we obtain

$$\psi(\tau,n)=\psi^{(n)}(\tau)=\frac{d^n\psi}{d\tau^n}=\frac{i^nn!}{(1-i\tau)^n}=\frac{i^n\Gamma(n+1)}{(1-i\tau)^n}$$

And, of course, the Gamma function is our pathway to any fractional derivative. Now, insofar as $\tau \in (-\infty,\infty)$ we can make a change of variables so that $\tau=\text{tan}\theta,\  \theta\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Then

$$\frac{1}{(1-i\tau)^n}\to \frac{1}{(1-i\text{tan}\theta)^n}=\text{cos}^{n+1}\theta \ e^{i(n+1)\theta}$$

As an example, we plot the ${i^{3/2}}^{th}$ derivative of the Cauchy pulse [note that $i^{3/2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i)$]. Clearly, we can create a infinite number of new plane curves in this manner.

For a more detailed description of the Cauchy pulse and related functions see [The Apple of My *i*](http://web.calstatela.edu/curvebank/waldman/waldman.htm). This was my first foray into recreational mathematics five years ago.

[image: The Apple of My *i*]