# Fractional derivative on circle

Tags: fourier-analysis, partial-fractions

I know the definition of a fractional derivative in x-axis in Fourier space:

$F(\partial^{\alpha}_x f(x) = -|k|^{\alpha} f(k)$

But I don't have any idea how to define fractional derivative on the boundary of a circle? Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this what you are after, but I am interpreting it as a desire to find the fractional derivative of a circle. I can accomplish this with ease in the complex plane. The details are explained in a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709673/is-there-a-notion-of-a-complex-derivative-or-complex-integral/2207605#2207605). There is a more extensive write-up [here](http://web.calstatela.edu/curvebank/waldman/waldman.htm) (see the linked PDF file).

The Cauchy pulse is defined as

$$\psi=\frac{1}{1-i\tau},\quad \tau\in(-\infty,\infty)$$

This function is amenable to the fractional calculus, as explained in the link and reference. If you plot $\psi$ in the complex plane you'll see that it is a circle. The equations in the link show how to get any real or complex fractional derivative (with an example).

Mathematically, the first derivative of $\psi$ is the cardioid. The fractional derivatives between, say

$$\frac{d^n\psi}{d\tau^n},\quad n\in[0,1]$$

exhibit a gradual change from the circle to the cardioid.

But the possibilities are endless.

Comment: I want fractional derivative in cylindrical or polar coordinate